# Contagem de palavras utilizando dicionário

Tags: python

Preciso contar as ocorrências de palavras em um texto tomando como referência uma lista de palavras pré determinadas. Transformei o texto em uma lista de `string`, as palavras estão em um conjunto (`set`)

```
 palavras_procuradas = {'de', 'solução', 'mesa', 'teste', 'acabaxi'}

 texto = ['para', 'validar', 'minha', 'solução', 'foi', 'preciso', 'fazer', 'o', 'teste', 'de', 'mesa', 'do', 'algoritmo', 'elaborado', 'só', 'depois', 'do', 'teste', 'de', 'mesa', 'que', 'o', 'programa', 'foi', 'implementado', 'essa', 'estratégia', 'poupou', 'bastan', 'te', 'tempo', 'de', 'desenvolvimento']

 dicionario = {}
 for palavra in texto:
     if palavra in palavras_procuradas:
         dicionario[palavra]= palavra += 1
 for chave in dicionario:
     print (chave + " " + dicionario[chave])
```

A saída correta seria:

```
  acabaxi 0
  teste 2
  mesa 2
  solução 1
  de 3
```

Na saída do meu Código está dando erro:

```
  dicionario[palavra]= palavra += 1
                              ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solução

Coloquei um contando que sempre é inicializa com 1, então ele verifica se a palavra já existe no dicionario, se for verdadeiro, pega o número da string, converte para inteiro e então atribui +1 e adiciona na string novamente, acrescentei mais um for para verificar as palavras que não estão no texto com o valor 0.

## Código

```
palavras_procuradas = {'de', 'solução', 'mesa', 'teste', 'acabaxi'}

texto = ['para', 'validar', 'minha', 'solução', 'foi', 'preciso', 'fazer', 'o', 'teste', 'de', 'mesa', 'do', 'algoritmo', 'elaborado', 'só', 'depois', 'do','teste', 'de', 'mesa', 'que', 'o', 'programa', 'foi', 'implementado', 'essa', 'estratégia', 'poupou', 'bastan', 'te', 'tempo', 'de', 'desenvolvimento']

dicionario = {}
for palavra in texto:
    if palavra in palavras_procuradas:
        count = 1
        if palavra in dicionario:
          count = int(dicionario[palavra].split(' ')[-1]) + 1;
        dicionario[palavra] = palavra + " " + str(count)

for palavra in palavras_procuradas:
  if palavra not in texto:
    dicionario[palavra] = palavra + " " + str(0)

for chave in dicionario:
    print (dicionario[chave])
```

## Resultado

```
solução 1
teste 2
de 3
mesa 2
acabaxi 0
```

## [Executar](https://repl.it/@WictorChaves/-293200)

Comment: Olá Wictor Chaves, isso a palavra abacaxi não consta no texto mas ela deve ser retornada com valor 0.

Comment: Tudo bem, vou fazer a alteração e já posto

Comment: Editado com a alteração desejada :)

Comment: Olá Wictor Chaves, muito obrigado amigo, sua solução funcionou perfeitamente, se eu conseguir chegar no nível de programação próximo ao seu já está bom pra mim. Valeu

Comment: Eu espero que você chegue mais longe do que eu :)

Answer (score 2):

Apenas como complemento à resposta que já tem, mostro outra alternativa de resolução utilizando [`Counter` de collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Esta é uma sub classe de dicionário que faz as contagens dos vários elementos recebidos na construção.

Aplicando diretamente o `Counter` à sua lista `texto` dá-lhe o seguinte resultado:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> dicionario = Counter(texto)
Counter({'de': 3, 'do': 2, 'teste': 2, 'o': 2, 'mesa': 2, 'foi': 2, 'te': 1, 'programa': 1, 'para': 1, 'tempo': 1, 'depois': 1, 'estratégia': 1, 'só': 1, 'implementado': 1, 'minha': 1, 'algoritmo': 1, 'essa': 1, 'preciso': 1, 'que': 1, 'solução': 1, 'desenvolvimento': 1, 'bastan': 1, 'elaborado': 1, 'fazer': 1, 'validar': 1, 'poupou': 1})
```

Aqui vê que ele contabilizou todas as palavras que lá existiam. Para incorporar na sua lógica precisa apenas de interpretar do `Counter` aquelas que está interessado:

```
from collections import Counter  # importação de Counter aqui

palavras_procuradas = {'de', 'solução', 'mesa', 'teste', 'acabaxi'}
texto = ['para', 'validar', 'minha', 'solução', 'foi', 'preciso', 'fazer', 'o', 'teste', 'de', 'mesa', 'do', 'algoritmo', 'elaborado', 'só', 'depois', 'do', 'teste', 'de', 'mesa', 'que', 'o', 'programa', 'foi', 'implementado', 'essa', 'estratégia', 'poupou', 'bastan', 'te', 'tempo', 'de', 'desenvolvimento']

dicionario = Counter(texto)

for palavra in palavras_procuradas:  # para cada palavra procurada
    # imprimir a palavra seguida da contagem, que é 0 se não existir
    print (palavra + " " + str(dicionario[palavra]) if palavra in palavras_procuradas else 0)
```

[Veja o exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/wYEHVc)

Comment: Isac, muito obrigado pelo código.

Comment: @Bruno Sem problema. Estamos ca para ajudar :)